# How to use Redirect in version 5 of react-router-dom of Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using the last version react-router module, named react-router-dom, that has become the default when developing web applications with React. I want to know how to make a redirection after a POST request. I have been making this code, but after the request, nothing happens. I review on the web, but all the data is about previous versions of the react router, and no with the last update.

Code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

import SignUpForm from '../../register/components/SignUpForm';
import styles from './PagesStyles.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Footer from '../../shared/components/Footer';

class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      client: {
        userclient: '',
        clientname: '',
        clientbusinessname: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
      }
    };

    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
    this.changeClient = this.changeClient.bind(this);
  }

  changeClient(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const client = this.state.client;
    client[field] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      client
    });
  }

  async processForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const userclient = this.state.client.userclient;
    const clientname = this.state.client.clientname;
    const clientbusinessname = this.state.client.clientbusinessname;
    const password = this.state.client.password;
    const confirmPassword = this.state.client.confirmPassword;
    const formData = { userclient, clientname, clientbusinessname, password, confirmPassword };

    axios.post('/signup', formData, { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          errors: {}
        });

        <Redirect to="/"/> // Here, nothings happens
      }).catch((error) => {
        const errors = error.response.data.errors ? error.response.data.errors : {};
        errors.summary = error.response.data.message;

        this.setState({
          errors
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.section}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <img src={require('./images/lisa_principal_bg.png')} className={styles.fullImageBackground} />
          <SignUpForm 
            onSubmit={this.processForm}
            onChange={this.changeClient}
            errors={this.state.errors}
            client={this.state.client}
          />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpPage;
```

Comment: Your `Redirect` looks like JSX, not JS.

Comment: can you provide you entire component code

Comment: Yes, I am using JSX. Well, maybe i need to clarify. The POST request is inside a REACT component that makes the request.

Comment: @KornholioBeavis, sure, now you can see complete. I make the server with expressjs, I don't know if you need this data

Comment: Can you validate that you are getting a callback response from axios.post? Also why are you using async function without await anywhere?

Comment: @KornholioBeavis, you are right, I missed to delete the word "async", because I was using it in order to receive the callback from axios in a variable, but I don't need it anymore. Yes, I am getting the response that I expect, and the response have the status OK (200)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You have to use `setState` to set a property that will render the `<Redirect>` inside your `render()` method.

E.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  handleSubmit () {
    axios.post(/**/)
      .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

     if (redirect) {
       return <Redirect to='/somewhere'/>;
     }

     return <RenderYourForm/>;
}
```

You can also see an example in the official documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

---

That said, I would suggest you to put the API call inside a service or something. Then you could just use the `history` object to route programatically. This is how the [integration with redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) works.

But I guess you have your reasons to do it this way.

Comment: @sebastian sebald what do you mean by: `put the API call inside a service or something` ?

Comment: Having such an (async) API call inside your component will make it harder to test and reuse. It is usually better to create a service and then use it (for example) in `componentDidMount`. Or even better, create a [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) that "wraps" your API.

Comment: Pay attention that you must include Redirect to use it in begin of file:
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Is it not possible at all to redirect with a function call instead of rendering a redirect-route?

Comment: Yes, under the hood `Redirect` is calling `history.replace`. If you want access to the `history` obect, use `withRoutet`/`Route`.

Comment: `react-router` >=5.1 now includes hooks, so you can just `const history = useHistory(); history.push("/myRoute")`

Comment: @Alex export 'Redirect' (imported as 'Redirect') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Answer (score 47):

Here a small example as response to the title as all mentioned examples are complicated in my opinion as well as the official one.

You should know how to transpile es2015 as well as make your server able to handle the redirect. Here is a snippet for express. More info related to this can be found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server).

Make sure to put this below all other routes.

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('distApp'));

/**
 * Enable routing with React.
 */
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('distApp', 'index.html'));
});
```

This is the .jsx file. Notice how the longest path comes first and get's more general. For the most general routes use the exact attribute.

```
// Relative imports
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// Absolute imports
import YourReactComp from './YourReactComp.jsx';

const root = document.getElementById('root');

const MainPage= () => (
  <div>Main Page</div>
);

const EditPage= () => (
  <div>Edit Page</div>
);

const NoMatch = () => (
  <p>No Match</p>
);

const RoutedApp = () => (
  <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/items/:id" component={EditPage} />
      <Route exact path="/items" component={MainPage} />          
      <Route path="/yourReactComp" component={YourReactComp} />
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/items" />)} />          
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />          
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, root);
```

Comment: this doesn't work all the time. if you have a redirect from `home/hello` > `home/hello/1` but then go to `home/hello` and hit enter it wont redirect the first time. any ideas why??

Comment: I advise you to use "create-react-app" if possible and follow the documentation from react-router. With "create-react-app" everything works fine for me. I was not able to adapt my own react application to new react-router.

Answer (score 42):

React Router v5 now allows you to simply redirect using history.push() thanks to the [useHistory() hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory()

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home")
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Now, we import everything from `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 23):

Simply call it inside any function you like.

```
this.props.history.push('/main');
```

Comment: what about outside component?

Comment: Look at these issues here:  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5237#issuecomment-376685224 @Nux

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

import SignUpForm from '../../register/components/SignUpForm';
import styles from './PagesStyles.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Footer from '../../shared/components/Footer';

class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      callbackResponse: null,
      client: {
        userclient: '',
        clientname: '',
        clientbusinessname: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
      }
    };

    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
    this.changeClient = this.changeClient.bind(this);
  }

  changeClient(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const client = this.state.client;
    client[field] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      client
    });
  }

  processForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const userclient = this.state.client.userclient;
    const clientname = this.state.client.clientname;
    const clientbusinessname = this.state.client.clientbusinessname;
    const password = this.state.client.password;
    const confirmPassword = this.state.client.confirmPassword;
    const formData = { userclient, clientname, clientbusinessname, password, confirmPassword };

    axios.post('/signup', formData, { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          callbackResponse: {response.data},
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        const errors = error.response.data.errors ? error.response.data.errors : {};
        errors.summary = error.response.data.message;

        this.setState({
          errors
        });
      });
  }

const renderMe = ()=>{
return(
this.state.callbackResponse
?  <SignUpForm 
            onSubmit={this.processForm}
            onChange={this.changeClient}
            errors={this.state.errors}
            client={this.state.client}
          />
: <Redirect to="/"/>
)}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.section}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <img src={require('./images/lisa_principal_bg.png')} className={styles.fullImageBackground} />
         {renderMe()}
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpPage;
```

Comment: You should not be making HTTP requests in your component files

Comment: Can you share what is inside import SignUpForm from '../../register/components/SignUpForm';? I am trying to learn from this. Though in my case, I am using a redux form

Answer (score 6):

**Update for `react-router-dom` v6**, there is a `useNavigate` hook for condtional redirection and `Link` component

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Example(): JSX.Element {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
      ...
      if(true) { // conditional redirection
       navigate('/not-found', { replace: true });
      }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
     ...
     <Link to="/home"> Home </Link> // relative link navigation to /home 
     ...
    </>
  );
}
```

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation) 
[Relative Link Component](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

Comment: For a more declarative approach you can use <Navigate to="/path" />, personally I prefer the hook approach (in the answer), but felt like mentioning this as well : )

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: Answering just the title of the question

Previous Version

```
<Redirect from="/old-url" to="/new-url" />
```

Latest version

```
<Route path="/old-url" element={<Navigate to="/new-url" />} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use `withRouter`. You can get access to the `history` object's properties and the closest `<Route>`'s `match` via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter` will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { withRouter } from "react-router"

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
  }
}
// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Or just:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
))
```

Comment: withRouter is now deprecated in v6

Answer (score 3):

The problem I run into is I have an existing IIS machine.  I then deploy a static React app to it.  When you use router, the URL that displays is actually virtual, not real.  If you hit F5 it goes to IIS, not index.js, and your return will be 404 file not found.   How I resolved it was simple.   I have a public folder in my react app.  In that public folder I created the same folder name as the virtual routing.  In this folder, I have an index.html with the following code:

```
<script>
  {
    sessionStorage.setItem("redirect", "/ansible/");
    location.href = "/";
  }
</script>
```

Now what this does is for this session, I'm adding the "routing" path I want it to go.  Then inside my App.js I do this (Note ... is other code but too much to put here for a demo):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Ansible from "./Development/Ansible";
import Code from "./Development/Code";
import Wood from "./WoodWorking";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const redirect = sessionStorage.getItem("redirect");

    if(redirect) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem("redirect");
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        {redirect ?<Redirect to={redirect}/> : ""}
        <div className="App">
        ...
          <Link to="/">
            <li>Home</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/dev">
            <li>Development</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/wood">
            <li>Wood Working</li>
          </Link>
        ...
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            render={(props) => (
              <Home {...props} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/dev"
            render={(props) => (
              <Code {...props} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/wood"
            render={(props) => (
              <Wood {...props} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/ansible/"
            exact
            render={(props) => (
              <Ansible {...props} checked={this.state.checked} />
            )}
          />
          ...
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Actual usage: [chizl.com](http://chizl.com)

**EDIT**: changed from localStorage to sessionStorage.   sessionStorage goes away when you close the tab or browser and cannot be read by other tabs in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

In v6 of react-router you can accomplish this using `<Navigate/>` tag as there is no `<Redirect/>` Component.

In my case. I was required to maintain the connection to the server between /Home route and /chat route; setting window.location to something would re-render that destroys client-server connection I did this.

```
 <div className="home-container">
      {redirect && <Navigate to="/chat"/>}
      <div className="home__title">
         ....
      <div className="home__group-list" onClick={handleJoin}>
</div>
```

```
const [redirect, doRedirect] = useState(false)
```

`handleJoin` changes the state of `redirect` to true.

Answer (score 2):

```
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
```

For navigate to another page (About page in my case), I installed `prop-types`. Then I import it in the corresponding component.And I used `this.context.router.history.push('/about')`.And it gets navigated.

My code is,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../assets/mystyle.css';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Header extends Component {   
    viewAbout() {
       this.context.router.history.push('/about')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <header className="App-header">
                <div className="myapp_menu">
                    <input type="button" value="Home" />
                    <input type="button" value="Services" />
                    <input type="button" value="Contact" />
                    <input type="button" value="About" onClick={() => { this.viewAbout() }} />
                </div>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
Header.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write a hoc for this purpose and write a method call redirect, here is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

const RedirectHoc = (WrappedComponent) => () => {
    const [routName, setRoutName] = useState("");
    const redirect = (to) => {
        setRoutName(to);
    };


    if (routName) {
        return <Redirect to={"/" + routName}/>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <WrappedComponent redirect={redirect}/>
        </>
    );
};

export default RedirectHoc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use React conditional rendering.

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserSignup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirect: false
    }
  }
render() {
 <React.Fragment>
   { this.state.redirect && <Redirect to="/signin" /> }   // you will be redirected to signin route
}
</React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: This worked but it is required to change "react-router" to "react-router-dom", else it will throw

Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you are using react-router v-6.0.0-beta or V6   in This version Redirect Changes to Navigate like this

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'; // like this CORRECT in v6
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; // like this CORRECT in v5

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; // like this WRONG in v6
// This will give you error in V6 of react-router and react-router dom

please make sure use both same version in package.json
{
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",   //Like this
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0", // like this
}

this above things only works well in react Router Version 6

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to navigate to another component is( Example
 navigates to mails component by click on icon):

```
<MailIcon 
  onClick={ () => { this.props.history.push('/mails') } }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to another component you can use `this.props.history.push('/main');`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

class Example extends Component {

  redirect() {
    this.props.history.push('/main')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.redirect()}
      </Fragment>
    );
   }
 }

 export default Example
```

Comment: React throws a warning: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Answer (score 0):

I found that place to put the redirect complent of react-router is in the method render, but if you want to redirect after some validation, by example, the best way to redirect is using the old reliable, window.location.href, i.e.:

```
evalSuccessResponse(data){
   if(data.code===200){
    window.location.href = urlOneSignHome;
   }else{
     //TODO Something
   }    
}
```

When you are programming React Native never will need to go outside of the app, and the mechanism to open another app is completely different.