# how can we achieve redirect using react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router, react-router-dom

I tried using

```
<Redirect to = 'loginPage' />
```

but it is not redirecting me anywhere. what should i do?

Please help me

Comment: use <Link to="url"/>

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: test by adding / to loginPage like this
<Redirect to = '/loginPage' />

another solution is to use browserHistory push. Google it you will find tons of examples

Comment: Redirect component needs to be rendered in order for it to work, if you are using in class methods, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Redirect in the new react-router-dom of Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to redirect:

**Option 1:**

Using `<Redirect />` like in this example:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: '/loginpage'
  }}
/>
```

This option works most of the times except for component lifecycle methods, such as ComponentDidMount where you need to opt for the second option below.

**Option 2:**

Using `this.props.history.push("/loginpage");` like in this example:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.authenticated === false) {
      this.props.history.push("/loginpage");
    }
  }
```

Note that to use this option, the component must be a child component of `<BrowserRouter />`. Otherwise, you have to use the `withRouter()` HOC like in this example:

```
myComponent = withRouter(
  ServicePlanSelect
);
```