# Redirecting a user to a different path in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a web app. The user can go and Read some info about an object from Firebase. The problem is the user can also be logged in with an Android app, and if a property on Firebase is changed, he needs to be kicked out of his current view on the web app. I know how to get this one done. This is the code:

```
var AssignedWordRef = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(currentUser.uid).child('assignedWork');
AssignedWordRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    var assignmentId = snapshot.val();
    if (assignmentId === null) {
        console.log('Redirect right here mate');
    }
});
```

And this works. It's console logging and all is great. But the problem is I need to redirect the user to a different path. So far I used a `window.location`, but it's a bad idea. Here are my `Routes`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/assignments" render={
        () => (firebase.auth().currentUser === null ?
            <Redirect to='/'/> : this.state.assignedWord === undefined ?
                <AssignmentsComponent/> :
                <Redirect to={'/assignment/' + this.state.assignedWord}/>)
    }/>

    <Route exact path='/assignment/:id' render={
        props => (
            firebase.auth().currentUser === null ?
                <Redirect to='/'/> : <CheckIfHasCurrentTasksComponent {...props}/>)
    }/>

    <Route exact path='/userPanel' render={
        () => (firebase.auth().currentUser === null ?
            <Redirect to='/'/> : <UserPannelComponent/>)
    }/>

    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent}/>
</Switch>
```

I tried returning the `<ComponentToRedirectTo/>` where the `console.log` is, but no luck.

Returning `<Redirect to='/assignments'/>` also didn't help. My guess is I have to put it in the `Route`, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: Would you tried `this.props.history.push(location)`?

Comment: You can use push or perform a redirect like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo that's perfect! Thank you! Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: You can use push or perform a redirect like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs

Comment: @alex.iron thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use push with this.props.history or just use the Redirect. This is an example code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs) (remember to use this.setState) to perform a new rendering:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  handleSubmit () {
    axios.post(/**/)
      .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

     if (redirect) {
       return <Redirect to='/somewhere'/>;
     }

     return <RenderYourForm/>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `this.props.history.push('/');` instead of using `<Redirect to='/' />`

Hope this will work!