# Unable to redirect to another page in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react page with the method below. When I click the button
 a method studentApproval() is called. 
 This method gets hit but I want a redirection  to another page once
 this is done. No redirection is happening. How can I make this redirection work?

This line is not working.

```
    this.props.history.push(STUDENT_FORMS_URL)
```

Button that gets clicked on the page

```
     <Button
        onClick={() => this.studentApproval()}
        className="next-button"                    
        >
        Approve<Icon>chevron_right</Icon>
     </Button>
```

This resides in another file.

```
    export const STUDENT_FORMS_URL = '/student-forms';
```

Method that gets hit on the click of the button.

```
      studentApproval(){
              AXIOS.post(`${API}/student-forms/check-request`, {
                action: "APPROVE",
                studentFormId: myId 
                },{
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  }
                }).then(res => {            
                  this.props.history.push(STUDENT_FORMS_URL)    
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                });                  
            }
```

Comment: Check out this answer. It explains everything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs . I could write an answer specifically for you, but I think this covers it...

Comment: i don't want to use redirect. cant push work?

Comment: Have you wrap the component inside `withRouter()` yet?

Comment: Yeah. I missed wrapping it withRouter. I will do that now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your component with withRouter(), and don't forget to pass history as a prop to your Router. Without this, your router will not trigger history.push() and the app will not be updated.

:)

Comment: Upvoted for the correct answer. However, a ref link or sample code would help future readers