# How do I redirect to another page on form submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect to a certain page once I post my form but it doesn't redirect, it only posts the form data and does not redirect to the stated page

I've tried appending the && operator in order for onSubmit to do both functions but to no avail. I also tried having both "onSubmit" and "onClick" but it's only "onSubmit" that works

```
//./userspost.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Form1 from "./form1";
import { createUsers } from "./actions/appactions";

class userspost extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  };
  setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    });
  };
  renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/users" />;
    }
  };
  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log("form submission data", data);
    createUsers(data);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <Form1 onSubmit={this.handleSubmit && this.setRedirect} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default userspost;
```

for the posting the form data

```
//./form1.js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
var createReactClass = require("create-react-class");
const Form1 = createReactClass({
  //setting initial state
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      firstName: this.props.firstName,
      lastName: this.props.lastName,
      userName: this.props.userName,
      role: this.props.role
    };
  },
  handleFirstChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleLastChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      lastName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleUserChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      userName: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleRoleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      role: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        name="categories_post"
        className="form-horizontal"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <div id="categories_post">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="firstName"
            >
              First Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.firstName}
                onChange={this.handleFirstChange}
                id="firstName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="lastName"
            >
              Last Name
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.lastName}
                onChange={this.handleLastChange}
                id="lastName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label
              className="col-sm-2 control-label required"
              htmlFor="userName"
            >
              UserName
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.userName}
                onChange={this.handleUserChange}
                id="userName"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-sm-2 control-label required" htmlFor="role">
              Role
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.role}
                onChange={this.handleRoleChange}
                id="role"
                required="required"
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button
                type="submit"
                id="categoriesSubmit"
                className="btn-default btn"
              >
                submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-2" />
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button className="btn btn-danger">
                <Link to="/users">Home</Link>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
export default Form1;
```

for posting using the fetch API

```
//./actions/appactions.js 
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

export function createCategories(data) {
  return fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/categories", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}
export function createUsers(data) {
  return fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/users/create", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}
export function createBusiness(data) {
  return fetch("https://localhost:44341/api/businesslistings/create", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are rendering the `Redirect` component along with the rest of your JSX everytime. Rendering only `<Redirect to="" />` should solve your problem.

```
class userspost extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  };
  setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    });
  };
  handleSubmit(data) {
    console.log("form submission data", data);
    createUsers(data);
  }
  render() {

    if( this.state.redirect ){
       return <Redirect to="users/" />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <Form1 onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, use only the `handleSubmit` function in your form onSubmit event. Since adding two functions with `&&` could cause unexpected results. And when everything is ready to redirect, just call your function `setRedirect`.

There is someone that already answered something similar, so I took a bit of help from there. Check it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230829/5568741