# How to route to an absolute path using react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app uses react-router to route between pages. 
The problem is this: 
I'm in a page in the following route: http://example.com/my-current-location/ and I want to route to http://example.com/my-next-location/

I tries using

```
this.props.history.push("/my-next-location")
```

but that takes my to http://example.com/my-current-location/my-next-location/
which is not what I need.

this.props.history.push("/my-next-location")

What I need is a way to navigate to absolute path. 
Of course,

```
location.replace()
```

won't do since I don't want a full page refresh. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi. Do you have the paths declared on your main react-router component? If you do it will be just a matter if using a `<Link />` in the place you want the linking button. Cheers!

Comment: check this link [How to use Redirect in the new react-router-dom of Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<Link />` or this component

```js
import React from 'react;
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";




/**
 * @param {boolean} props.redirect 
 */

const index = props =>{

return props.redirect ? 
<Redirect to="/my-next-location" />
:<div>
   the components code
</div>

}
```