# Redirect on button click in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Can anyone please tell me how redirect works in react?

I'm from Angular background and trying to learn React.

I have a small application, where I want to redirect the user to `profile` component on click of a button.

This is a very basic requirement but there's no proper documentation available (or I'm not able to find one).

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact render={props => <Index {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/login-page" exact render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/profile-page" exact render={props => <Profile {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" exact render={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

```
<Button color='primary' onClick={e => this.viewProfile()}>View Profile</Button>

viewProfile = function () {
          console.log("clicked");
      }
```

Comment: Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Redirect in the new react-router-dom of Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

Comment: Yes I saw this solution, but what does  return <Redirect to='/somewhere'/>; means? It's giving error as 'Redirect' is not defined.

Comment: import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import it from react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router comes with a `Link` component that can be used for this. Just import it, set the destination in the `to` prop, and wrap your `Button` with it:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to='/profile-page'>
   <Button color='primary' onClick={e => this.viewProfile()}>View Profile</Button>
</Link>

viewProfile = function () {
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

Have a look at the React Router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), they've got a lot of useful info!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Link` component from react-router-dom:

```
<Link to="/profile">View profile</Link>
```

Check out the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) as well, they provide a lot of examples

Answer (score 3):

You can call up the `useHistory()` hook to navigate.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const yourComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  viewProfile = function() {
    history.push("/new-url");
  };
  return (
    <Button color="primary" onClick={viewProfile}>
      View Profile
    </Button>
  );
};
```

If you are using a class component you can wrap it `withRouter()` to gain access to the same `history` object.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  viewProfile = function() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/new-url");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.viewProfile}>
        View Profile
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this solved my problem.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'


      state = {
          redirect: false
         }

        const { redirect } = this.state;

        if (redirect) {
          return <Redirect to='/profile-page'/>;
        }


      viewProfile = function () {
          console.log("clicked");
          this.setState({ redirect: true })
      }
```

thanks @tarzen chugh, @Good Samaritan for you response

Answer (score 0):

Nomenclature is important when you are first learning a new framework :)

Strictly speaking a [redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) will

> Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack

What you want is *navigating* to the profile page. There are two ways you can achieve this

1. Through JSX [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md).
2. Programmatically with the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4) object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Test extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={}
  }
  
  viewProfile = () => {
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push('profile-page');
  }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Test extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={}
  }
  
  viewProfile = () => {
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push('profile-page');
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Button
        color='primary'
        onClick={() => this.viewProfile()}>
        View Profile
      />
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`. It's simple solution

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const navigate = useNavigate();

const navigateDashboard = (event) => {
    navigate("/dashboard");
};

<Button color='primary' onClick={navigateDashboard}>View Profile</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use `withRouter` HOC to do redirects.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Component extends React.Component {
  viewProfile = function () {
     console.log("clicked");
     this.props.history.push('/main');
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <Button color='primary' onClick={e => this.viewProfile()}>View Profile</Button>        
    )
  }

}
export default withRouter(Component);
```

Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score -1):

Do like this :-

```
<Button color='primary' onClick={() => this.viewProfile()}>View Profile</Button>
```

---

```
viewProfile= () => {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/profile-page",
          }}
        />
      );
  };
```