# Go to a link when clicked inside a Table.Row with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, semantic-ui, react-router-dom

I have a table and I want each [row](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/) to be clickable and when you click on it to go to that link (which is different for each row).

```
<Table.Body>
  {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <Table.Row
      key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}
      onClick={() => {
        <Link
          to={
            entityName && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`
          }
        />;
      }}>
      ...
    </Table.Row>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

So I did it like above, added a  component but doesn't work. It says:

**Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions**

I'm using `Table` / `Table.Row` from `Semantic UI` and `Link` from `react-router-dom`. I cannot change the `Table` but the `Link` component isn't mandatory. It would be great anyway if it can redirect to that link when it's clicked.

Is it any way to do this?

Comment: This could be usefull [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

Comment: Are you using hooks? or the class-based comp.

Comment: @Jon, I tried that way but it doesn't work becasue my link is personalized for each row, it has its row id in it. it that example they are setting the state of something on true and when it's true the page redirects to the same link

Comment: @SultanH., it's a class-based component. Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/KVUa71Rk, where I put alert("HERE") it should be the link part

Comment: k.s. answer below will work for you, use the -older version of react- ref in order to have the full aspect of it, I'll suggest an edit for k.s.'s answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be is to use the history to navigate from the component. To get the history object, you either need to use the `useHistory()` hook which is available from [react-router:5.1.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0) or if you are using [a older version of react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components)

1. you will have to add a method that does it:

**Functional**

```
const onNavigate = (entityName, idList) => () => {
  entityName && history.push( && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`) // change accordingly 
}
```

**Class**

```
onNavigate = (entityName, idList) {
  return function () {
    return entityName && this.props.history.push( && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`) // change accordingly 
  }
}
```

This method returns a function reference, so that the `onCLick` prop doesn't trigger it on render and `some_props` will be visible in the inside function thanks to [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

2. you pass the method to the `onClick` method:

```
<Table.Body>
  {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
    <Table.Row
      key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}
      onClick={onNavigate(enitityName, idList)}
    >
      ...
    </Table.Row>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

this way the click handler will receive the a function reference and should navigate to the according url

Comment: where should be onNavigate declared? inside render? or it is a method outside of render

Comment: I'm showed how to use it in a functional component. I'll update for a class based

Comment: this is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/KVUa71Rkm, where I put alert("HERE") it should be the link part

Comment: This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff.

Comment: you should use the **Class** example

Comment: so I made the changes, here is the modified file: https://pastebin.com/4D3aFw63, I guess there is a problem with `this.props.history` because that doesn't exist. I added logs and clicked on the first row from the table and this is what it shows: https://i.imgur.com/hePDIt7.png, there is no `this.props.history`, should it be add somewhere?

Comment: I added instructions on how to add history to the app. It must be a component which is used for routing though, or you need to pass it through props to this one. Use http://codesandbox.io/ to show some workable example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-router` to link inside the react application you can use the `useHistory` hook and push the new path.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Component() {
  let history = useHistory();

  return (
    <Table.Body>
      {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
        <Table.Row
          key={idList && idList[rowIndex]}
          onClick={() =>
            history.push(
              entityName && `/${entityName}/${idList[rows.indexOf(row)]}`
            )
          }
        >
          ...
        </Table.Row>
      ))}
    </Table.Body>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get this error message: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app